# rails save select_tag value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I'am using `select_tag` and when I update selected value is not stored

when i update :name, :tag value get first option

edit.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for(@name) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lname%><br />
    <%= f.text_field :lname%>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tag %><br />
    <%= f.select :tag, "<option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option>".html_safe %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

**Solution**

```
<%= f.collection_select(:tag, [1,2], :to_i, :to_s, :prompt => 'Categories') %>
```

Comment: Please add more code and info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
<%= f.collection_select(:tag, [1,2], :to_i, :to_s, :prompt => 'Categories') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe?

```
= f.select :tag, (1..4).to_a, :prompt => '---'
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use select tag from this link

[select_tag](http://shiningthrough.co.uk/Select-helper-methods-in-Ruby-on-Rails)

```
<%= select_tag "tag", "<option>1</option><option>2</option>" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= f.select "tag", "<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>".html_safe %>
```

read http://ashleyangell.com/2009/11/form-select-helper-in-ruby-on-rails/